# Java Check if multiple strings are empty

Tags: java, string, joptionpane, is-empty

I am trying to add a User into a LinkedList using Java, but I am wondering if there is a shorter way to check if multiple strings are empty instead of using if statements everytime I input a new string

This is the method I came up with

```
    public void addUser() {
        int error = 0;
        
        do {
            Users user = new Users();
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your name");
            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                error = 1;
            } else {
                String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a password");
                if (password.isEmpty()) {
                    error = 1;
                } else {
                    // more string inputs
                }
            }

        } while (error != 0);
    }
```

Comment: You can avoid the nesting by skipping the `else` and calling `continue;` instead of relying on `error`.

Comment: Either you pass the loop one time or infinite, because you don't set `error` back to 0 at next loop (should happen at the beginning of the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a separate method to read the input data until a valid string is provided and call this method with custom prompt:

```java
private static String readInput(String prompt) {
    String input;
    do {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt);
    } while (input == null || input.isEmpty());
}

public void addUser() {
    String name = readInput("Enter your name");
    String password = readInput("Enter a password");
// ...
    User user = new User(name, password, ...);
// ...
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't restart the input loop on error, as it does in the question.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was trying to look for!

Comment: @shmosel that loop is moved inside `readInput` method, and in the original implementation an error would cause to re-input all the fields from the start

Comment: That's what I said